# iOS/OSX Equivalent of SetEvent() and WaitForSingleObject()?

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, semaphore

I have a cross-platform app that builds on Windows, iOS and OSX.

In my Windows app I create an Event object with an initial state of unsignalled. I have a thread which waits for this Event to be signalled by calling WaitForSingleObject(). WaitForSingleObject() blocks the processing of the thread until such time that another thread calls SetEvent().

How do I achieve the same behaviour with GCD dispatch_semaphore_wait() and dispatch_semaphore_signal() ?

I've tried the following:

Child thread:

```
void *UpdateThread( void *pParams )
{
  for( ;; )
  {
    // Decrease the semaphore count, similar to sem_wait()
    dispatch_semaphore_wait( g_hEvtNeedMore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER );
    BigSoundBufferUpdate();
  }
}

// SetEvent() - Windows equivalent 
void SetEvent( dispatch_semaphore_t sem )
{
  // Increase semaphore count - similar to sem_post()
  dispatch_semaphore_signal( sem );
}
```

Main thread:

```
g_hEvtNeedMore = dispatch_semaphore_create( 1 ); // Not sure if initial value should be 0 or 1
pthread_create( &hUpdateThread, NULL, UpdateThread, NULL );
...


// Tell the child thread we want more data..
SetEvent( g_hEvtNeedMore );
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but while I'm assuming you're trying to maximize cross platform compatibility of your code base, it's worth noting that writing multi-threaded code on iOS/MacOS is generally simplified if you avoid creating threads manually and instead use GCD more thoroughly. See [Migrating Away from Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) in the _Concurrency Programming Guide._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically right, though you generally would `dispatch_semaphore_create(0)` (which means the `dispatch_semaphore_wait` will wait until it receives `dispatch_semaphore_signal`; i.e., it is "an object with an initial state of unsignalled"). If you use `1`, the first call to `dispatch_semaphore_wait` will be satisfied immediately, not actually waiting for any signal (though after calling `BigSoundBufferUpdate` once, the second iteration of that `for` loop will wait for a signal).

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence - I've accepted your answer.